# Docker compose simple routing for Mysql router

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

```
    version: '3.1'
services:
  Mysql:
    image:
      mysql-router:latest
    hostname: mysql-router
    environment:
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_HOST: 192.168.1.1
      MYSQL_PORT: xx
      MYSQL_USER: xxx
```

I would like to deploy a Mysql router with a docker-compose file on 192.168.1.2 and I will like to make it route to another MySQL router, the MYSQL_HOST is the destination (192.168.1.1). I get the error message said that the 192.168.1.1 contain MySQL InnoDB cluster but schema doesn't exist, I understand the solution can be added/adopt group replication deployment but I have no idea why there is a cluster because all I want to do is just simple routing from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.1. I appreciate if someone have an idea about what go wring here